# RcppArmadillo: failing to install on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to install Rcpp on Ubuntu. Here are some environment details:

```
R version:3.4.0
g++ --version: Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4
```

If I have a blank `Makevars` file, RcppArmadillo can be installed but with some warnings about OpenMp

```
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
In file included from ../inst/include/armadillo:52:0,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:46,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
                 from RcppArmadillo.cpp:22:
../inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:487:118: note: #pragma message: WARNING: support for OpenMP requires C++11/C++14; add -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 to compiler flags
   #pragma message ("WARNING: support for OpenMP requires C++11/C++14; add -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 to compiler flags")
                                                                                                                      ^
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from ../inst/include/armadillo:52:0,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:46,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
../inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:487:118: note: #pragma message: WARNING: support for OpenMP requires C++11/C++14; add -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 to compiler flags
   #pragma message ("WARNING: support for OpenMP requires C++11/C++14; add -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 to compiler flags")
                                                                                                                      ^
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
In file included from ../inst/include/armadillo:52:0,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:46,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
                 from fastLm.cpp:22:
../inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:487:118: note: #pragma message: WARNING: support for OpenMP requires C++11/C++14; add -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 to compiler flags
   #pragma message ("WARNING: support for OpenMP requires C++11/C++14; add -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 to compiler flags")
                                                                                                                      ^
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -fopenmp -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RcppArmadillo)
```

After I added `PKG_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11` to `Makevars`, I got a error message as following:

```
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -std=c++11 -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
RcppArmadillo.cpp:22:27: fatal error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe for target 'RcppArmadillo.o' failed
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo’
* restoring previous ‘/home/march/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
```

The wield thing is that when I tried to re-install RcppArmadillo on my mac(10.11), the same problem occurred. Could anybody enlighten me?

Comment: You know Ubuntu is the OS I do most of my development (and work) on so I can pretty much assure you that every version of RcppArmadillo ever released worked on it....

Comment: Please use `CXX_STD = CXX11` instead of `PKG_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11` in `~/.R/Makevars`.

Comment: Also, `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpparmadillo` also gets you a version, either slightly dated from the distro, or mostly current from Michael's repos (see the [README at CRAN for more](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu)) so it clearly builds.

Comment: Also, your statement above about _If I have a blank `Makevars` file,_ is suspicious.  We never tell you to use a blank one. `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` does not install a blank one.

Comment: @coatless I tried this but still got the same warnings about OpenMp.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi Dirk, Thanks for your reply. 'A blank `Makevars` file' means that I comment out all of the lines. I also have tried  install some old versions of RcppArmadillo but still failed. I installed RcppArmadillo many many times on my Ubuntu and MacOS these years and never failed before.

Comment: "I deleted all files and it stopped working" -- seriously, you can't randomly delete stuff and then come to us for help.

Comment: Also: Your first attempt actually _worked and succeeded_ and your second attempt was just wrong as @coatless already pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 16.10 which I have here at hone, if you wish I can repeat it at work tomorrow with 16.04:

```
edd@bud:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
edd@bud:~$ Rscript -e 'install.packages("RcppArmadillo")'
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.7.960.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1115539 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether ccache g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... ccache g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether ccache g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ version is sufficient... (6.2.0) yes
checking LAPACK_LIBS... system LAPACK found
checking for OpenMP... found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating inst/include/RcppArmadilloLapack.h
** libs
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Werror -march=native -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Werror -march=native -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Werror -march=native -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
ccache g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -fopenmp -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RcppArmadillo)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp2hQNrn/downloaded_packages’
edd@bud:~$
```

That I usee `ccache` is not material.  This. Just. Works.

Comment: Thank you sir. I think I can live with my first attempt since it works:)

Comment: I just checked, and under _Ubuntu 16.04_ I get the same warnings as g++ 5.* used. Under the current _Ubuntu 17.04_ (which I use) you do _not_ get the warnigs as g++ 6.* automatically turns on C++11.  We have refrained from enforcing C++11 to not pose even more constraints on useable systems.

Comment: Also, feel free to "accept" the answer (click on tick-symbol only you see as you asked the question) and/or "upvote' (click on up-arrow).  That is how StackOverflow works :)

Comment: Thanks for the accept, and for "reminding" me of the `#pragma` warning on older compilers.  I may bite the bullet and make the package require C++11.

Comment: I updated to 17.04 this morning and the warnings get away. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, thanks to `g++-6`.  You could also have add `-std=c++11` to the local flags in `~/.R/Makevars`.   But updating is good in its own right :)